# vim editor error color

Tags: vim, colors

I am using Vim 7.3 on Ubuntu. Problem is - whenever I got some error in my code, that error is marked with white color. I can't see anything underneath that color. So if I have typo error (missing one brace) it will mark that brace with white, but I wont be able to see that mistake ( it is covered with color ). Sometimes it marks all line.  I am using *Molokai* color scheme.

I tried to change color scheme, but nothing happens. I suppose that error color is coming from the vim native settings.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: @Ingo Karkat's answer will solve it I think. But you can also try to set this `:set t_Co=256` (before that you can see what the setting is now with `:set t_Co?)`. I'm also on Ubuntu with Vim 7.3, I did that and many color schemes works better, they are designed for many colors. I had 8 as default for `t_Co`. You must have that **in the beginning of your `.vimrc` file** if you try it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The

```
:hi
```

command lists all defined highlightings. Find the one with the white color (for errors, this should be `Error`), and change it (see `:help :highlight`) in your `~/.vimrc`, e.g.:

```
:hi Error ctermfg=Red guifg=Red
```

Comment: Hi;
Your answer led me to right direction.
I found this solution, ant put this line in my .vimrc:
    :highlight clear SpellBad

Comment: Thumbs up for telling about the `:hi` command. Awesome to be able to see all the colors, and then easy to modify after. Thank you!

Comment: Another way to visualize the highliting schema is by running this command (from gvim help):  
    so $VIMRUNTIME/syntax/hitest.vim

Answer (score 1):

If highlighting is the issue, then you can easily and quickly turn off all highlighting by typing ":noh" (without the quotes) from command mode.  This will temporarily turn off highlighting.  This also works for getting rid of highlighting after a search (which really annoys me because like your problem here, I can't read the text when it's highlighted).

If you haven't already, you should create a file in your home directory named ".vimrc", so pathing it out would be "~/.vimrc".  This is the what @mtk is referring to (just in case you don't know that already.  Some people at work use Vim but don't know about the .vimrc file).

Comment: thanks for help;
I am using custom vim settings from this guy http://spf13.com/post/perfect-vimrc-vim-config-file/
It is a massive collection of bundles,color-schemes and all other goodies, which I modified in my .vimrc If you need help with sp13 just let me know

Comment: Yes! I have :noh lound to F12 and use it all the time to clear search highlighting, like so:   map <f12> :noh<CR>